Can I mix noun and verb objects with 'velle'?
As far as I know, the following two are grammatically valid:


Panem et aquam volo.
I want bread and water.




Edere et bibere volo.
I want to eat and drink.


In the first sentence the objects of velle are nouns, in the second one they are verbs.
When a verb is used as an object or a subject, it takes the infinitive form, so 1 and 2 strike me as very similar constructions.
However, this sounds off to me (in both Latin and English):


Panem et bibere volo.
I want bread and to drink.


Am I correct in thinking that 1 and 2 are good but 3 is bad Latin?
Is there a way of thinking about these two kinds of objects that makes this behavior natural, or should not mixing different object types be treated as a separate rule?

Semantic syllepsis, isn't it?
